# Adding auto increment value to li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

im a css/designer guy so please excuse my lameness in not knowing any .js

basically i want to know how to add an auto incremental id to a list item with javascript / jquery for something that i am trying to add some css to.

before

```
<li id=""><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
<li id=""><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
<li id=""><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
```

after

```
<li id="1"><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
<li id="2"><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
<li id="3"><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
```

thanks in advance and especially just for reading this

tried all the responses, nothing has worked on a plain html page with nothing but the ul/li items.

thanks to all that tried, i have failed in a big way.....im not a coder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give your `li` tags an encompassing `ul` with an `id` in case there are other `li` tags on the page that you don't want to order, but in jQuery this is pretty easy for:

```
<ul id="ordered">
    <li><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You would simply use the `each` method:

```
$('#ordered li').each(function(i,el){
    el.id = i+1;
});
```

I would recommend using something other than just a plain integer for an id though, so maybe something like `'ordered' + (i+1)` instead of just `i+1` above.

Comment: mixed the both answers and got the result i was wanting....once again a big big thank you from the 'average joe' that doesnt code

Answer (score 0):

Your tags say jQuery, so:

```
$("li").each(function(i){this.id = i})
```

So you can learn: you make a collection of HTML nodes with the `$('foo')` syntax. You use CSS selectors, so `li` will get -every- `<li>` on the page.

`.each` loops over those collected HTML elements, and does something to them. The 'something' is in the code `function(i){this.id = i}`. jQuery passes which loop you're on to the function as `i`, and the code inside the curly braces sets the id of that particular element to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need id's for styling, that's a bad idea. What you should do is use css 3 pseudo class :nth-child(n) which is in your area of css.

Comment: I would use the CSS3 `:nth-child(n)` as well, however you couldn't rely on it working in older browsers. For commercial design where accessibility is important, it's not the best way to go.

Comment: Well you could say the same way that some people don't have JS enabled so then again your solution wont' work. Nothing is bulletproof sadly.

Comment: True :) Whilst I'm not sure, I would guess that the number of XP users stuck on IE8 (or less) would exceed those with JavaScript disabled. Although, if you wanted to be as safe as possible, using both would probably do the trick ;)

Comment: Why don't you do this ID assignment then trough a serverside language? That way you're 100% sure your elements have an ID assigned

Comment: It would, but presumably there is a reason why it needs to be done at the client end, otherwise we'd _probably_ be answering a different question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to wrap your code in a div so it's easier to code for

```
<div id="increment">
<li><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
</div>
```

And js would be:

```
function loadcode(){
    var increments = document.getElementById("increment");
    var li = increments.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i=0;i<li.length;i++) li[i].setAttribute("id", i+1);
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<body onload="loadcode()">
```

Comment: tried this on a plain html page and still not getting any love. thanks for your time

Comment: Are you trying to generate the HTML so you can copy paste it somewhere? or change it upon page load? Also I changed the code a bit.

Comment: works!!!! thank you so so much. im only ok with design..code kills me, have a great day ultimatebuster and everyone else who read my dilemma