# Increment list items classes

Tags: jquery, css, list, show-hide, increment

I want to create a list with incremented ids and hrefs using jQuery. Is this possible?

```
<ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#item1">Item number 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item2">Item number 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item3">Item number 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item4">Item number 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item5">Item number 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="toShow">
    <div id="item1" style="display:block;"></div>
    <div id="item2" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="item3" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="item4" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="item5" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

These list items will be generated via a loop and I want to use this plugin http://www.bijusubhash.com/demo/show-hide-a-div-at-a-time-with-jquery/

Thanks,
David

Comment: could you tell us what have you tried in jquery part.

Comment: I have looked at this solution but I wanted to be more specific in my question as i am using additional jQuery for the ShowHide effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006001/adding-auto-increment-value-to-li-element thanks, David

Comment: You'd like to put the `<li>` elements manually and just dynamically increment ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume that: What you need actually is much more simpler than you think:

### *[demo link](http://jsbin.com/oyavuz/3/edit)*

HTML: (yes, NO custom ID's mess)

```
<ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="toShow">
    <div>First element</div>
    <div>Second element</div>
    <div>Third element</div>
    <div>Fourth element</div>
    <div>Fifth element</div>
</div>
```

And a couple of jQuery lines:

```
$('#toShow>div:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all but first
$('#links li').on('click',function(e){
    $('#toShow>div:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show(1700).siblings('div').stop(1).hide(1700);
    return false;
});
```

More info:
http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Ah, so does this now pair up (.siblings) the child divs/items in order?

Comment: Exactly. As you can see 'on click' we take the 'button' index: `$(this).index()` and we search for the same index children <div> to open, and the same time we toggle all <div> siblings.

Comment: @DavidHaigh For a better explanation we do: `showDIVsameIndexAsButton and hideThisDIVsiblingsDIVS` and all that using the `:eq()` selector.

Comment: @DavidHaigh You're welcome. PS: the `.stop(1)` in the code helps us to prevent animations buildups clearing the animation queue, so on fast clicks the animations will not be accumulated, but cleared. I reedited my demo as I put .stop(1) on the wrong place. **Please adjust it in your script accordingly**. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

This div will contain generated items. You can append those list elsewhere.

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var ul = $('<ul id="links"></ul>'),  // creates an ul
        div = $('<div id="toShow"></div>'); // creates a div

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { // loop for add item (suppose five items)
      ul.append('<li id="list_'+ i +'"><a href="#item'+ i +'">Item number '+ i +'</a></li>');
      div.append('<div id="item'+ i +'" style="display:block;">Item '+ i +'</div>');
    }

    $('#container').append(ul, div); // append those ul and div to document give life
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8MWBw/)**

Comment: Could you possible talk me though your answer? I'd like to achieve my goal but also understand what I'm doing...

Comment: Also, this may be a little naive of me but how can i test this locally without any loop?

Comment: @DavidHaigh without loop how can you add multiple items? I made a fiddle for you and you can test there